# Next.js prevent router.back() from roting back to another site

Tags: next.js, single-page-application, back, next-router

On my web app I have a blog. On each post there are a back button, not the browser back button, which should lead the user back to where they came from. Since the blog post can be linked from multiple routes I can't have a static back path.

Therefore I tried using the `route.back()` method. However if the user came from Facebook or another site they will go back to that site. I understand that this is the intended behavior of the method but I don't think that is what the user expects when they press the custom back button. Instead I want to route them back to the homepage.

I have tried using the `document.referrer` but since I use Next.js `document.referrer` is always empty. Also this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72511360/can-i-detect-if-using-next-js-router-back-will-leave-my-site-and-do-a-router-p) is not working anymore.

Have I missed something or is there any other elegant or non-elegant solutions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.